# Compile error with function void

Tags: c

In c programming language, i get compile error in this function, can someone tell me what's wrong? I get this after compiling:

> tak.c: In function ‘ispis’: tak.c:30:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects
>   argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]

Here is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct takmicar {
    char ime[20];
    char prez[20];
    int god;
    char drz[4];
};

void ispis (struct takmicar niz[50], int n) {
int i;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf ("%s %s %d %s \n", niz[i].ime, niz[i].prez, &niz[i].god, niz[i].drz);
}
}
```

Comment: Just change `&niz[i].god` to `niz[i].god`. If you wanted to output the pointer address then change `%d` to `%p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because you are trying to print an integer, but you are using.

```
&niz[i].god
```

As an argument, instead of.

```
niz[i].god
```

In C, the & operator return the address of a variable, which should be handled by a pointer, so if you want to print the address of `niz[i].god` change `%d` to `%p`.

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is being extremely helpful as having a mismatch in the `printf` formatting string and the corresponding values will give you *undefined behaviour* at run time.

If you want to display the value, then write `niz[i].god` (i.e. drop the address-of operator `&`).

If you want to display the *pointer* value, then write `printf ("%s %s %p %s \n", ...)`. `%p` is the format specifier for a pointer.